# How can I transform an Extended Backus Naur Grammar to its normal representation?

Tags: algorithm, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, ebnf

I have a grammar that contains expressions between brackets '{}' which represents 0 or more times that expression, and expressions between square brackets '[]', which represent 1 or none times that expression, I think this kind of grammars are called Extended Backus-Naur Form Grammars. 
I would like to transform the grammar to its normal form (where there are not brackets nor square brackets).

Is there an existing algorithm to do that?

I know that I can substitute something like A--> B[CD]E  to A-->BE, A--> BCDE but I would like to know if there are existing algorithms that I could implement in order to transform those expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do that is to replace every EBNF construct with a new rule. Here are the equivalences you can use:

**Option**

```
A ::= B [C D] E ;
```

```
A ::= B X E ;
X ::= C D | ɛ ;
```

Where ɛ represents the empty string.

**Repetition**

```
A ::= B {C D} E ;
```

Zero or more times:

```
A ::= B X E ;
X ::= C D X | ɛ ;
```

One or more times:

```
A ::= B X E ;
X ::= C D | C D X ;
```

**Grouping**

```
A ::= B (C D) E ;
```

```
A ::= B X E ;
X ::= C D ;
```

Apply these transformations recursively and you'll end up with vanilla BNF.

Comment: Thank you very much! There´s no specific name for this kind of transformations right?

Comment: I'm sure there must be a specific term for that but right now I just can't seem to remember what it is...

Comment: Hello again, I was thinking about the '{}' substitution and I think another way of writing it is X--> CD| '#'. Where '#' is epsilon.

Comment: @Pablo yes that's true. I must admit I don't remember the formal syntax very well. Since *epsilon* represents the empty string that would be the correct way of writing it (I edited the answer).

Comment: Correcting my previous comment, the '{}'  could be replaced by X--> CDX| '#'.

Comment: @Pablo I initially got this wrong. I've defined `{}` as *one or more times* but it should be *zero or more times*, and your rule is correct in this case. I've left both in the answer for the sake of completeness, just in case.